# Self Join in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Category` class. It is also a self-join. I have used repository pattern. Using the repository works fine for get, insert or of update data. But when I want to get data from a relational entity, it does not work. It throws this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

But, when I get data using `DbContext` it works fine.

```
public class Category
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

        //Navigation
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration for self join

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .WithOne(x => x.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey(g => g.CategoryId);
```

Repository class for getting all data

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult LoadCategory()
{
     var categories = unitOfWork.Category
                                .GetAll()
                                .ToList()
                                .Select(x => new
                                             {
                                                  Id = x.Id,
                                                  Name = x.Name,
                                                  CategoryName = x.Parent.Name
                                             }).ToList();
    return Json(categories);
}
```

In that last method, I get the error, but when I use

```
ProductDbContext db = new ProductDbContext();
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

LoadCategory not working right? 
Suppose that you create new instance of db as general, on top;
and use like this if it is work? Try this;

```
 [HttpGet]
public JsonResult LoadCategory()
{
     var categories = unitOfWork.Category
                                .GetAll()
                                .Select(x => new
                                             {
                                                  Id = x.Id,
                                                  Name = x.Name,
                                                  CategoryName = x.Parent.Name
                                             }).ToList();
    return Json(categories);
}
```

Comment: GetAll is tested. and it is using more then 20 times in my code with out problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. CategoryId is null-able. So if any item CategoryId is null then it throw error. I just check if null then neme will be blank.

```
var categories = unitOfWork.Category
                           .GetAll()
                           .Select(x => new
                                         {
                                           Id = x.Id,
                                           Name = x.Name,
                                           CategoryName = x.CategoryId == null ? "" : x.Parent.Name

                                         }).ToList();
```